# What's the best way to implement recurring events in FullCalendar via PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm getting ready to use the JQuery-based FullCalendar in my online app using PHP/MySQL and noticed that when implementing recurring events, you must place a new item in the event array for each recurrence (using the same ID), like this:

```
events: [
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d-1, 16, 0),
        allDay: false
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d+6, 16, 0),
        allDay: false
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d+13, 16, 0),
        allDay: false
    }
]
```

Okay, so that's not a big deal.  Using MySQL, I'll just feed in the event looped a bunch of times, like maybe 100 in the future from the start date of that event if it doesn't have an end date.  But now I'm loading up the page with a bunch of JavaScript that might not even be needed (if the user just opens the calendar to see one month).  Not cool.

There has to be a better way... does anyone have their own experience with this?

Comment: How are you storing these events in your database?  You can ajax-load these events based on actions on the calender, but you are likely to suffer longer load times by dispatching many AJAX calls than passing a larger result just once (HTTP handshakes are very slow compared to gzip data transfer).  You could select only relevant dates and ajax-load new events on a "next-month" event.

Comment: That was my worry... I didn't want to overload the server with many AJAX calls, but I also wanted to avoid filling the page with what could be thousands of events if I used the Events array shown above.  I was hoping there was some happy medium somewhere.  BTW, the events are stored very basically in MySQL... each one simply has a start date, a recurrence (daily, weekly, monthly, etc..), and an optional end date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FullCalender will by default fetch events for the current time-frame using lazyFetching.  Generally, this means you'll only send-off an ajax call when the user switches out the current month.  You can reduce server load by turning off caching:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Further, you should optimize your SQL on the server to only fetch events in a given timeframe:

> FullCalendar will determine the date-range it needs events for and will pass that information along in GET parameters.  ... Here is a URL that FullCalendar might visit:
>
> /myfeed.php?start=1262332800&end=1265011200&_=1263178646

If you use these get parameters in your SQL, you'll drastically reduce the data you need to send to the client:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE start > PARAMS_START_DATE AND end < PARAMS_END_DATE
```

Obviously, this won't be as succinct when using recurring events, you may for example (in pseudo-code):

```
recurring_events.each do |recurring_event|
  running_date = recurring_event.starts_on
  while running_date < PARAMS_END_DATE
    if running_date > PARAMS_START_DATE
      events.push { :event => event.id, :date => running.date, ... }
    end
    running_date = running_date + recurring_event.frequency_as_days
  end
end
```

This way, you'll just send back to full calendar what is applicable for the current view.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was hoping for. Thanks ghayes!